# Laravel and Angular: Update method not working

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am new to this "Angular/Laravel" thing.
I am trying to make a simple todo app. Adding and deleting work, but updating doesn't.

I have a ng-repeat section, and inside every todo I have an input.

```
    <label class="css-label to-do-name" ng-hide="editingFormBoolean">
    <input class="css-checkbox" name="todo-checkbox-{{todo.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
    {{todo.name}}
    </label>
```

app.js factory called TasksData:

```
    update: function (id) {
        return $http.put('/tasks/' + id);
    },
```

app.js directive[link:]
-this is called when the input changes, I am using $watch element

```
TasksData.update(scope.todo.id);
```

TaskController.php:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id);

    $task->done = Input::get('todo-checkbox-'+$id);

    $task->save();
}
```

But the Input::get doesn't work. If I replace "Input::get('todo-checkbox-'+$id)" with true or false values, the hole thing works, the data is sent to the database and updated. If you know how to get this done, or know any other way to mark a todo as completed, I will be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update: function (id) {
    return $http.put('/tasks/' + id, {isDone: $scope.todo.done});
},

public function update($id)
{
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);

    $task->done = Input::get('isDone');

    $task->save();
}
```

Comment: Hey @mcmjon!
Because I have multiple todos in a ng-repeat directive, I modified the code a bit.

`update: function (id, data) {
    return $http.put('/tasks/' + id, {isDone: data});
},`

`TasksData.update(scope.todo.id, scope.todo.done);`

Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it!